# Finding nodes that ends with 4 digits in xpath 1.0

Tags: xpath

How can I find the nodes that ends with 4 digits using xpath 1.0?

The following xpath works fine:

```
//*[substring(., string-length(.) - 3) = '2020']
```

But only find the year 2020, as expected. I tried using the translate function but does not seem to translate the string:

```
//*[translate(substring(., string-length(.) - 3), '0123456789', 'X') = 'XXXX']

<root>
  <year>November 2020</year>
  <year>October 1998</year>
  <year>November-20</year>
  <year>02/02/2001</year>
  <year>2020, May 20th</year>
  <year>July 3rd</year>
  <year>Missing</year>
  <year>Invalid</year>

</root>
```

Comment: Please, on XPath questions, always say which version of XPath you are using.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I updated to 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`translate` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-translate) docs say:

> If there is a character in the second argument string with no character at a corresponding position in the third argument string (because the second argument string is longer than the third argument string), then occurrences of that character in the first argument string are removed.

So you could change your translate version slightly to:

```
//*[translate(substring(., string-length(.) - 3), '0123456789', 'XXXXXXXXXX') = 'XXXX']
```

which should provide what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant, but this expression

```
//year[string(number(substring(., string-length(.) - 3)))!="NaN"]/number(substring(., string-length(.) - 3))
```

should output:

```
2020
1998
2001
```

Comment: This is an XPath 2.0 expression. If XPath 2.0 is available then it can be done much more simply using `matches(., '[0-9]{4}$')`